# Why is the hamburger menu block not displaying when open?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to use CSS Grid and Flexbox for creating my webpage.

For the header, I have successfully implemented the logo to be inline with the navigation for screens larger than 800px (just for example case), and when the screen is sized down the navigation links disappear and a hamburger icon appears. Great! Only, I can't get the links to reappear when I open the hamburger menu. I tried different variations of grabbing the block of links through selecting the class name and id of the ul tag as well as different variations of displaying them (i.e. flex, block, inline-block, etc.), but nothing has worked.

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">WEBSITE LOGO</a>
        </div>
        <label class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" aria-label="Open navigation menu" for="menu-toggle">
          <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
            </span>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul class="main-nav" id="navigation">
              <li><a href="index.html">VISIT</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-us.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="connect.html">CONNECT</a></li>
                <li><a href="resources.html">RESOURCES</a></li>
                <li><a href="get-the-app.html">GET THE APP</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

```
html {
  /* border-box box model allows us to add padding and border to our elements without increasing their size */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* A system font stack so things load nice and quick! */
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--darkBlue);
}

/*
  We inherit box-sizing: border-box; from our <html> selector
  Apparently this is a bit better than applying box-sizing: border-box; directly to the * selector
*/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: var(--white);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header";
}

/* -------  GRID AREAS  ------- */

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "logo nav nav";
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
}

.logo a {
  color: #008CE2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: menu-icon;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* -------  NAVIGATION  ------- */

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: #008CE2;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.logo a:hover,.main-nav a:hover {
  color: #ff6600;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#menu-toggle:checked + #navigation {
    display: flex;
}

/* ------- Media Queries ------- */

@media(max-width: 800px){

  .header {
    grid-area: header;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "logo menu-icon";
  }

  .hamburger {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .nav {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }

  .main-nav {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-nav li {
    display: block;
  }

  #menu-toggle:checked + .main-nav {
    display: block;
  }

}
```

```
// Look for .hamburger
  var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  // On click
  hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Toggle class "is-active"
  hamburger.classList.toggle("is-active");
  });
```

What is the reason for this not displaying? And is there a better method for displaying/hiding the block of links?

https://codepen.io/halebales24/pen/VNMvRL

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:
Since the `.main-nav` ul block had `display: none;` and something needed to undo that, by adding a new .is-open class so when it is open I can display my content:

```
html {
  /* border-box box model allows us to add padding and border to our elements without increasing their size */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* A system font stack so things load nice and quick! */
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--darkBlue);
}

/*
  We inherit box-sizing: border-box; from our <html> selector
  Apparently this is a bit better than applying box-sizing: border-box; directly to the * selector
*/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: var(--white);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header";
}

/* -------  GRID AREAS  ------- */

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "logo nav nav";
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
}

.logo a {
  color: #008CE2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: menu-icon;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* -------  NAVIGATION  ------- */

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: #008CE2;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.logo a:hover,.main-nav a:hover {
  color: #ff6600;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#menu-toggle:checked + #navigation {
    display: flex;
}

/* ------- Media Queries ------- */

@media(max-width: 800px){

  .header {
    grid-area: header;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "logo menu-icon";
  }

  .hamburger {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .nav {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }

  .main-nav {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-nav.is-open{
    display:block;
  }

  .main-nav li {
    display: block;
  }

  #menu-toggle:checked + .main-nav {
    display: block;
  }

}
```

```
// Look for .hamburger
  var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  var mainNav = document.querySelector(".main-nav");
  // On click
  hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Toggle class "is-active"
  hamburger.classList.toggle("is-active");
  mainNav.classList.toggle("is-open");
  });
```